# How to get criteria column dynamically using INDEX+VLOOKUP in Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

One good soul has helped me get to this point, but I got one more contraint I'm trying to tackle:

How to populate **Rep** and **Region** based on the **ID** column, but this column may move, so getting this must be dynamic, just like getting **Rep** and **Region** columns is.

Here's the working formula, without the criteria:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(ROW('From Sheet1'!A7:A); {ROW('From Sheet1'!A7:A)\ 'From Sheet1'!B7:C}; MATCH({"Rep"\ "Region"}; 'From Sheet1'!A7:C7; 0); 0))
```

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing) a sample data.

Appreciate your help, as usual!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A7:A, 
 {FILTER('From Sheet1'!A7:Z, 'From Sheet1'!7:7="ID"), 'From Sheet1'!B7:C}, 
 MATCH({"Rep", "Region"}, 'From Sheet1'!A7:C7), 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Does it take into account the ID column in Sheet2?

Comment: @santosOnit yes. answer and your sheet are updated

Comment: I've made the following mod. to it, but it says it throws ```#REF``` error. ```=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Z10, 
 {FILTER(Orders!A5:BC, Orders!5:5="ID"), Orders!B5:BC}, 
 MATCH({"Fabric"}, Orders!A5:BC5), 0)))``` In this case, instead of comparing to column A, it'd compare to a specific cell. Sorry I know that this wasn't the question but the nature is so similar. Thank you!

Comment: @santosOnit can you share a copy / sample of your sheet?

Comment: I've tested it in the sheet I shared above and it works. Not the same on an official file I'm working on. I guess I don't understand ```{FILTER(Orders!A5:BC, Orders!5:5="ID"), Orders!B5:BC}``` more especifically.

Comment: @santosOnit it means you create an array of two ranges. first range is made by FILTER where we look for entire range A5:BC and in row 5 we search for "ID". the output of filter is 1 column. after FILTER() there is a comma. it means we wana put next range next to 1st range (semicolon ; would mean to put next range under first range. note that if your locale is not english the comma , needs to be a backslash \ ...maybe that's the reason why it wont work on your original sheet - hard to guess if not seen) and then the 2nd range is B5:BC

Comment: Hey so why did you post. Did mine not work or was it too long? I was just wondering... yours is obviously more elegant but was my answer wrong?

Comment: @GabrielPierce I never tested it.

Comment: @player0 oh.. okay.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a doozy

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A7:A,{INDIRECT("'From Sheet1'!"&LEFT(ADDRESS(7,MATCH("ID",'From Sheet1'!7:7,0),4))&"7:"&LEFT(ADDRESS(7,MATCH("ID",'From Sheet1'!7:7,0),4))),INDIRECT("'From Sheet1'!"&LEFT(ADDRESS(7,MATCH("Rep",'From Sheet1'!7:7,0),4))&"7:"&LEFT(ADDRESS(7,MATCH("Rep",'From Sheet1'!7:7,0),4))),INDIRECT("'From Sheet1'!"&LEFT(ADDRESS(7,MATCH("Region",'From Sheet1'!7:7,0),4))&"7:"&LEFT(ADDRESS(7,MATCH("Region",'From Sheet1'!7:7,0),4)))},{2,3}))
```

In the place of that formula you had in cell B7, This is also assuming your headers are in row 7 on sheet1.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!